# How to remove last character put to std::cout?

Tags: c++, stdout, cout

Is it possible on Windows without using WinAPI?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You may not remove last character.

But you can get the similar effect by overwriting the last character.
For that, you need to move the console cursor backwards by outputting a '\b' (backspace) character like shown below.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hi";
    cout<<'\b';  //Cursor moves 1 position backwards
    cout<<" ";   //Overwrites letter 'i' with space
}
```

So the output would be

> H

Comment: You do have to be careful that cout doesn't decide to `flush` itself before the backspace has been inserted.

Comment: I can't seem to erase a new line with this method.

Comment: Using backspace character is actually multi-platform as I had tested it on Linux and it works. To do "console animations" like progress bars, first disable buffering in std::cout by adding this at the start of main function std::cout << unitbuf; Now printing a '\b' will remove a char in the real console, not in the std::cout internal buffer. I don't know if std::cout buffers the '\b' or interprets it and delete a character from its internal buffer when buffering is on.

Comment: However, if you redirect the output to the file, then ^H and the preceding character will still be present there.

Comment: Only works on a terminal. Breaks if you output to a pipe or a file. Won't recommend.

Answer (score 9):

This code does exactly that:

```c
std::cout<<"\b \b";
```

Comment: But if u use stringstream and compare stringstream::str() it to other strings, it won't match. This only applies to printing in the terminal

Comment: Edit: Oh, so you're moving backwards, writing a space, and then moving backwards again.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You can't without accessing the console's api that is never standard.

Comment: sorry  , you can , see my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `cin.get()` to delete last char