# Remove trailing comma in C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

How can I remove a trailing comma from the end of the line, output from an array?

```
for ( k = numEntries - 1; k >= i; k--)
    myArray[k] = myArray[k - 1];
myArray[i] = newValue;

for (i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
    cout << myArray[i];
    cout << ",";
}
```

Comment: Really and brutally hard to do in the general case. It's easier by far to not put the comma there in the first place. There's going to be a duplicate question for this.

Comment: Semi-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745861/how-to-remove-last-character-put-to-stdcout (semi because backspace doesn't always work)

Comment: Whole raft of ways to prevent writing the last delimiter: [Printing lists with commas C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c)

Answer (score 3):

For starters this loop

```
for ( k = numEntries - 1; k >= i; k--)
                          ^^^^^^
    myArray[k] = myArray[k - 1];
```

is incorrect. It is evident (due to this statement `myArray[i] = newValue;`) that you mean

```
for ( k = numEntries - 1; k > i; k--)
                          ^^^^^
    myArray[k] = myArray[k - 1];
```

As for your question then the second loop can look like

```
for (i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
    if ( i != 0 ) cout << ",";
    cout << myArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I always use (invented as answer to a challenge question):

```
char const* prefix = "";
for (auto& element : myArray) {
    std::cout << prefix << element;
    prefix = ", ";
}
```

which is maximal compact without introducing a branch / conditional in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

E.g. like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
    cout << myArray[i];
    if (i < numEntries - 1) cout << ",";
}
```