# How to delete a previous cout in c++

Tags: c++, cout

I would like to know the generic way to do it. Therefore, imagine I print "hello world" and then I want to delete that line from the screen. How would you do it? Btw, is there a general way to do it? or there is a specific way depending on what you are trying to delete?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove last character put to std::cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745861/how-to-remove-last-character-put-to-stdcout)

Comment: Print backspaces? Use a curses-like library?

Comment: Imagine this: what if your terminal isn't a screen at all, but a teletype? As far as C++ knows, that may be the situation.

Comment: IT depends on what device you outputted "Hello World" to. `C++` has no control over it. Different devices/terminal emulators have different control code sequences. Some more popular than others.

Comment: @FredLarson If you're sufficiently-aged to remember hammering out code on a [decwriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DECwriter), as I am (started out on one first year in college), *respect*.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yep, been there, done that.

Comment: There is no generic answer - the answer depends on which OS and which device (as mentioned by @Galik) you are using.  Some devices are not capable of backspacing.  Do you have a std::endl after the "Hello World"?